# php: find any combination of 2 or 3 numbers in string and separate as variable

Tags: php, string, variables, split, explode

How can I find if a combination of 2 or 3 numbers exists in string and then split it in two variables?

example: `$input = "this and that 12"` or `$input = "this and that 100"`

I want to separate this strings into two variables:

```
$text = "this and that",
```

`$number = "12"` (or "100" as in the above example)

P.S string is user input and could as well not contain any number, example `$input = "this and that";`

Comment: Is number always at the end of string? Only one number?

Comment: yes always at the end, it can be 2 or 3 digits

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried but should work.

```
$number = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $string );
$text = str_replace($number, "", $string);
```

Comment: how do you limit the number to exactly 2 or 3 digits in that code?

Comment: It will give you the whole number. Tell me what should happen if number is 1000. if its more than say 999, you can disallow it or less than 10.

Comment: shouldn't you check if there is a number in the string first? with preg_match? Say string doesn't contain any number ...

Comment: well then $number will be `null` and when you ll try to replace it, php wont replace it. so at the end your `$number` will be `null` which is right coz there is no number and `$text` will be the same string with no changes which is also right. Using this way u skip if conditions. dont worry php wont raise error if it doesnt find a number in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
$aStrings = array('This and that 123','This and Not That 12');

foreach($aStrings as $str){
preg_match('/\D+/',$str, $text);
preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $num);

echo "
$text[0]
$num[0]
- - - - 
";
}
```

Output:

```
This and that 
123
- - - - 

This and Not That 
12
- - - -
```

[Example Code](http://ideone.com/JWsqfo)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I have onlye one string and that it's user input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
$string1 = "this and that 12"; 
$string2 = "this and that 100";
$combine = explode(' ',$string1.' '.$string2);
$vars  = '';
$integer ='';
foreach($combine as $key =>$val)
{
    if(is_numeric($val))
    {
        $vars[] = $val;
    }
    else
    {
        $integer[] =$val;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r(array_unique($vars));
echo "<pre>"; print_r(array_unique($integer));
?>
```

this will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 100
)

Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => and
    [2] => that
)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I have onlye one string and that it's user input.

Comment: so you just use  $combine = explode(' ',$string1); and delete string 2, rest of the code is same

Answer (score 0):

you try this code

```
$string="this and that 12";//this and that 100
preg_match_all('/^([^\d]+)(\d+)/', $string, $match);

echo $text = $match[1][0];
echo $num = $match[2][0];
```